# Python - L error in declaration

Tags: python, error-handling, declaration

I have tried to use this code: http://www.cgtk.co.uk/data/gemf/generate_efficient_map_file.py  to create GEMF file from map tiles. Problem is, when I run this code with specific folder as a parameter, eg. "py generate_efficient_map_file.py Mapnik", I get error on line 6.

> File "generate_efficient_map_file.py", line 6 file_size_limit = 2000000000L

And mistake is in word L. How to solve this, when there is a declaration error?

Thx

Comment: It looks like you're running Python 3, and that module only supports Python 2. [The "L" suffix does not exists (and is not required) in Python 3](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#long-integers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it like this

```
python generate_efficient_map_file.py dirname
```

This works fine for me (no line 6 error - I don't have input data) on python 2.7.3.  You can check your python version with

```
python -V
```

Comment: Thanks, I have 3.3, I will try to download Python 2.7.3, thanks